# Intellisense not working in other file(s) when using imports (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am having an issue with VS-Code's intellisense. I am currently working on a Typescript Electron project which uses imports in the renderer process. But, when using imports to create functions in a file, referencing them in another file does not seem to work (Also breaks intellisense).

**Import ts File**

```
import { ipcRenderer as ipc } from "electron";

const api = (request:string) : void => {
    return ipc.send(request)
}

const app = {
    close: () => {
        return api('close');
    },
    minimize: () => {
        return api('minimize');
    },
    maximize: () => {
        return api('maximize');
    }
}
```

**Separate ts file**
[image: Attached Image]